# DotNetNuke 7 removes DLL's during extension installation

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have an extension that worked with previous versions of DotNetNuke.  I'm working on trying to update it, however whenever I install it into DNN 7 the installation process appears to strip the DLL's that are a key part of the extension.  In previous versions of DNN there was an option during the install process that needed to be checked to allow these to be installed, however there appears to be no such option during the install process in DNN 7.  Is it located elsewhere now?  I don't believe I can just drop the files into the directory where they're supposed to be, but if I can a heads up would be nice.

This has happened both on a client's server and my localhost, so I'm guessing it's an across the board thing.  Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information or I'm missing something big.

Answer (score 1):

Are the assemblies being installed into the `bin` folder, or some unusual place?  Are you using an [Assembly component](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/AssemblyComponent) to include these DLLs?  If you're installing into the `bin` folder via the Assembly component, that's good, otherwise DNN might be stopping you from including the assemblies for security reasons.

The only reason that files would be deleted during an installation would be because you have a [Cleanup component](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/CleanupComponent) defined in your manifest.  I'm assuming that you're using a DNN 5-style manifest (rather than the older manifest from DNN 4 and earlier).  If you're using the older type of packaging, the cleanup component would be defined as a text file matching the version number (e.g. `01.00.05.txt`).